# Space optimization for the UNIX sort -m command?

Tags: bash, unix, sorting

I'm trying to run a permutation test, which involves merging a thousand very large pre-sorted files into one mega sorted file.

The current run has some files that are even larger than those I usually merge (68M to 106M each).

I don't have enough hard drive space for the inputs, the temporary intermediates, and the outputs all at the same time. Is there a way to destructively merge all of these files using `sort`?

Here's the command I'm currently using:

```
sort -T /media/WD_Book/tmp --compress-program=gzip -g -k 6 -m *.rand.tab > /media/WD_Book/output/merged.rand.tab
```

(The files are numbered `0001.rand.tab` through `1000.rand.tab`, and the sort key is in exponential notation in the 6th column [thus `-k 6` and `-g`].)

I know it's possible to run a non-merge `sort` in-place, but the manpage specifically says it won't work for `-m`.

Comment: Could you store the inputs and the output if there were no intermediaries? If the files are pre-sorted you could hack away some perl/c/python to do the merging. If not you could merge them one by one and deleting the remnants.

Comment: howabout taking file 0001 and copy it into a file called "huge", delete 0001, concatenate 0002 into "huge, delete 0002 and so on and then sort the 1 and only huge-file in-place?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that way (WARNING: may wipe data.)

```
touch merged.rand.tab  # Create a zero-sized result file
for file in [0-9]*.rand.tab; do
   sort -k 6 -g -m merged.rand.tab $file > result.rand.tab
   rm -f merged.rand.tab
   mv result.rand.tab merged.rand.tab
   # you can rm $file if space is really scarce.
done
```

Basically exchanging space for time. You merge one file at a time with the result of the previous merging. Also, you can remove the already merged file.

Again, backup your data before trying. ;-)

Comment: I would merge the shortest two files together at each step if possible. Alternatively, assume that all the 1000 files are similarly sized and merge them in pairs or perhaps groups of 10.

Comment: You could approximate the former by sorting the input files by size. for file in \`ls -Sr [0-9]*.rand.tab\` IIRC.